# Bit manipulation for big integer classes?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, biginteger

I'm having a problem coming up with an algorithm for a big integer class in C++. My initial idea was using arrays/lists, but it's very inefficient. I then discovered about things like the following class:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CppIntegerClass.aspx

However, I find that approach really confusing. I don't know how to work with bit manipulations, and I barely understood the code. Someone please explain to me how to utilise bit manipulation, how it works, etc. Eventually I would like to create my own big integer class, but I'm barely a novice programmer and I just learned how to use classes.

Basically my question is:
How do I use bit manipulation to create a big integer class? How does it work??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading up on [binary numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) in  general. That page shows how the common arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction etc) work on binary numbers, i.e. how the numbers are manipulated bit by bit to get the desired result.

Mapping that into a programming  language such as C++ should be pretty straight-forward once you know *why* there are bit-manipulating operations being used.

In my experience, the most obvious bit-oriented thing needed when implementing something like this is bit *testing*, to check for overflow. Let's say you represent your big binary number as an array of `uint16_t`, i.e. chunks of 16 bits. When implementing addition, you will start at the least significant end of both numbers, and add those. If the sum is larger than 65,535, you need to "carry" one to the next `uint16_t`, just as when you add decimal numbers one digit at a time.

This can be implemented with a test like so:

```
const uint16_t *number1;
const uint16_t *number2;

/* assume code goes here to set up the number1 and number2 pointers. */

/* Compute sum of 16 bits. */
uint16_t carry = 0;
uint32_t sum = number1[0] + number2[0];

/* One way of testing for overflow: */
if (sum & (1 << 16))
 carry = 1;
```

Here, the `1 << 16` expressions creates a mask by shifting a 1 sixteen steps to the left. The `&` bitwise and operator tests the sum against the mask; the result will be non-zero (i.e. true, in C++) if bit 16 is set in `sum`.

Comment: But won't the outcome be too big for any standard data type? How do I handle that?